# updating value of array of object using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

My state object is:

```
[
    {
        traveller1_dob: '',
        traveller1_firstName:'',
        traveller1_isPreviousTraveller: false,
        traveller1_surname:'',
        traveller1_title: ''
    },
    {
        traveller2_dob: '',
        traveller2_firstName:'',
        traveller2_isPreviousTraveller: false,
        traveller2_surname:'',
        traveller2_title: ''
    }

]
```

and my payload is:

```
{key: "traveller1_firstName", value: "ABC", index: 0}
```

- key is the property of the object that needs to be updated
- value: is the value we want to update
- index: is the index of the traveller in state array

At the moment this is the way I updated:

```
let obj = state[payload.index];
obj[payload.key] = payload.value;

return _.unionBy(state, [obj], payload.key);
```

I am aware its not the best way.

Output should be:

```
[
    {
        traveller1_dob: '',
        traveller1_firstName:'ABC',
        traveller1_isPreviousTraveller: false,
        traveller1_surname:'',
        traveller1_title: ''
    },
    {
        traveller2_dob: '',
        traveller2_firstName:'',
        traveller2_isPreviousTraveller: false,
        traveller2_surname:'',
        traveller2_title: ''
    }

]
```

Ideally I want to get rid of index if it's possible.How would you do this?

Comment: I guess a simple operation like this would do  data[payload.index][payload.key] = payload.value; not much different from what you did earlier but it is better since it is able to do it in one step.

Comment: but if you want to do it point free form without variables you could libraries like ramdajs instead of lodash to do so like this https://jsfiddle.net/cdxaefvg/

Comment: If you notice I manipulated the state obj directly as well. which i not a good idea

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cdxaefvg/

Comment: you could try _.set but it also mutates the object in lodash

Comment: What's the point of an array of objects when the individual objects have uniquely numbered property names? Wouldn't it make more sense for both objects to have the same (un-numbered) properties, and then reference traveler 1 or 2 by its array index?

Comment: @nnnnnn you are right! I may need to change my model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, you can get rid of the index, and just map over your state and check `hasOwnProperty` on each stateItem and compare them to the `payload.key`. The snippet below should solve your problem:

```js
let state = [{
        traveller1_dob: '',
        traveller1_firstName: '',
        traveller1_isPreviousTraveller: false,
        traveller1_surname: '',
        traveller1_title: ''
    }, {
        traveller2_dob: '',
        traveller2_firstName: '',
        traveller2_isPreviousTraveller: false,
        traveller2_surname: '',
        traveller2_title: ''
    }

];


function updateState(payload) {

    const updatedState = _.map(state, stateItem => {
        if (stateItem.hasOwnProperty(payload.key)) {
            stateItem[payload.key] = payload.value;
        }
        return stateItem;
    });

    console.log(updatedState);
    return updatedState;
}

const samplePayload = {
    key: "traveller1_firstName",
    value: "ABC",
    index: 0
};

updateState(samplePayload);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank! I like your answer because its flat structure that having object of objects which was recommended by others.